# Negating SQL WHERE condition with nullable fields

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, nullable

I have a filter where user can select operations like **is**, **contains**, etc...

- **bubu is xoxo** translates into `WHERE lower(bubu) = 'xoxo'` SQL WHERE condition.
- **bubu contains xoxo** translates into `WHERE bubu ILIKE '%xoxo%'` SQL WHERE condition.

Now I have added the negative variants - **is not**, **does not contain**, etc.. I do not want to rewrite the WHERE conditions from scratch, so I prepend `NOT` to the already existing ones:

- **bubu is not xoxo** translates into `WHERE NOT lower(bubu) = 'xoxo'` SQL WHERE condition.
- **bubu does not contain xoxo** translates into `WHERE NOT bubu ILIKE '%xoxo%'` SQL WHERE condition.

However, there is a problem. If **bubu** is a nullable field and it actually has NULL in it, then the negative WHERE condition does not pick it, although from the human perspective (as opposed to SQL) the NULL value should satisfy the **bubu is not xoxo** filter.

I solve this problem by modifying the original positive WHERE condition like this:

- **bubu is xoxo** translates into `WHERE (lower(bubu) = 'xoxo' AND bubu IS NOT NULL)` SQL WHERE condition.

Then, the negation yields:

- **bubu is not xoxo** translates into `WHERE NOT (lower(bubu) = 'xoxo' AND bubu IS NOT NULL)` SQL WHERE condition.

And this time the NULL values are picked up correctly. The same problem is with the **contains** filter.

Is there a more elegant solution to resolve this inconsistency between how humans treat NULL and how SQL does it?

I am using PostgreSQL 9.2 and I do not mind having a solution specific to this database.

P.S.

Please, note that I want the **negative** expression to be of the form **NOT positive**.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to get away with using [COALESCE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) to convert your NULLs to empty strings:

```
-- These skip skips NULLs
lower(coalesce(bubu, '')) = 'xoxo'
coalesce(bubu, '') ilike '%xo%'

-- These will find NULLs
not lower(coalesce(bubu, '')) = 'xoxo'
not coalesce(bubu, '') ilike '%xo%'
```

Of course, this sort of trickery will run into problems if you're searching for empty strings, in such cases you'll need a context-sensitive sentinel value so that you can intelligently choose something that cannot possibly match your search term.

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8bbd2/3

Comment: +1. Question - Is using COALESCE more efficient than what I am doing?

Comment: I'd think that COALESCE would be the same or close enough that it wouldn't make any measurable difference.

Answer (score 0):

For the `=` operator you can use the `is [not] distinct from` construct

```
WHERE (lower(bubu) is not distinct from 'xoxo')
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-comparison.html

Comment: This is not good enough for me, because the negative version is not generated from the positive using the NOT operator.